# Why does (A'+ AC) = (A'+C)?

Tags: boolean-algebra

Why does (A'+ AC) = (A'+C)?

I can understand this via a truth table, but I cannot see why this works in boolean algebra. Conceptually I understand that A doesn't matter, but I can not seem to prove this. Can someone lend some advice?

[image]

Comment: Try this using Truth table.

Comment: I understand the truth table. Would you like me to show you the truth table I have?

Comment: I am trying to see how to prove this, using the distributive law doesn't work for me.

Comment: See this answer, I think, this should satisfy you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$A'+AC=A'(1+C)+AC=A'+(A'+A)C=A'+C$$

Comment: How are we able to get A'(1+C)?

Comment: $1+C=1$, for whatever $C$ be ($0$ or $1$). So, $A'=A'\times 1=A'\times (1+C)$. Now, did you got?

Comment: That makes since, but how does A =(A'+A)?

Comment: I never told $A=(A'+A)$, it is $A'(1+C)+AC=A'+A'C+AC=A'+(A+A')C$. Now, $A+A'=1$. So, your result.

Comment: I understand now, thank you very much for your help/

Answer (score 0):

In general, in boolean algebra we also have $X+YZ=(X+Y)(X+Z)$.